# The mysqli class couldn't possibly contain a 'price' - atrribute or could it?

Tags: php, mysqli

This is more of a theoretical question. I'm trying to build a shopping cart system for my online pizzashop webapp using an example bookstore out of *php and mysql development* book by luke welling and laura thomson.

in the code below, there is the $item variable that is an object. That object appears to have that price attribute. As far as I can judge you're tracing this object back to the mysqli class. Since I'm using netbeans, the contained mysqli.php file is hidden. and I can't find the price attribute in any other mysqli.php file on my computer.

Then again, I'm pretty sure there is no price attribute in the mysqli class because it would make no sense at all, but then where COULD the attribute possibly come from?

```
if (is_array($bestelling))
    {
        $conn = connect2db();
        foreach ($bestelling as $isbn => $key)
        {
        $query  = "SELECT pizza_price FROM pizzas WHERE Pizza_id = $pizzaId";
        $result = $conn->query($query);   
            if ($result)
            {
                $item = $result->fetch_object();
                $item_price = $item->price;
            }
        }        
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

No `$item->pizza_price;` refers to a piece of data in a row that you get from the database. I'm going to assume the database has a column named `pizza_price`. So `$item->pizza_price;` will contain values from here.

Comment: Since the query directly above only selects the column `pizza_price`, I'm assuming that or `$item->price` is a typo.

Comment: @veredesmarald Having read some tutorial books floating around, that wouldn't exactly be a surprise :). Modified my answer as well.

Comment: YES that is exactly it. Since in Netbeans the attribute 'price' (the way it is typed in the course) lights up in green, it looks like it's somewhere where it's truly recognized but now I realized it lights up in green no matter what you would be typin there after that arrow. The pizza_price colum makes an awful lot of sense of course.

Comment: @the_visit glad it's sorted. :)

Answer (score 0):

[`fetch_object()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php) returns

> an object with string properties that corresponds to the fetched row or NULL if there are no more rows in resultset.